# How to find a Image using Image name(String) in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, .net-4.0, silverlight-4.0

I have created a page which contains several controls, in this i have to get a image which is in the page. I have the image name as string value. I have made a for loop to find the image and return, but it is tedious while looping all the controls in the page if it is more and it is getting much time too.

// Passing the string and find as image

```
Image imgBack = FindControl<Image>((UIElement)Layout, typeof(Image), strSelectedimg);
```

// Function to find image

```
public T FindControl<T>(UIElement parent, Type targetType, string ControlName) where T : FrameworkElement
{
        if (parent == null) return null;
        if (parent.GetType() == targetType && ((T)parent).Name == ControlName)
        {
            return (T)parent;
        }
        T result = null;
        int count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            UIElement child = (UIElement)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
            if (FindControl<T>(child, targetType, ControlName) != null)
            {
                 result = FindControl<T>(child, targetType, ControlName);
                 break;
            }
         }
         return result;
     }
```

Is there any other easy way to find the image in the page using the string value.?

Comment: How do the images get onto the page? Are they added at run time, or are they defined in the static XAML code?

Comment: @Andrew: They are defined at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could build a lookup at the same time you're adding the images. If you post your code that adds the images at runtime, I could give you a more exact answer; but I'm thinking something like this:

```
private Dictionary<string, Image> _imageLookup;

private class ImageInfo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Uri { get; set; }
}

private void AddImages(ImageInfo[] imageInfos)
{
    this._imageLookup = new Dictionary<string, Image>();
    foreach (var info in imageInfos)
    {
        var img = CreateImage(info.Name, info.Uri);
        if (!this._imageLookup.ContainsKey(info.Name))
        {
            this._imageLookup.Add(info.Name, img);
        }
        AddImageToUI(img);
    }
}

private Image CreateImage(string name, string uri)
{
    // TODO: Implement
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

private void AddImageToUI(Image img)
{
    // TODO: Implement
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Then you could easily find the image later:

```
public Image FindControl(string strSelectedImg)
{
    if (this._imageLookup.ContainsKey(strSelectedImg))
    {
        return this._imageLookup[strSelectedImg];
    }
    else
    {
        return null; // Or maybe throw exception
    }
}
```

If you need to find more than just images, you could use a `Dictionary<string, Control>` or `Dictionary<string, UIElement>` instead.

Comment: How can i add a single image multiple times from a location. By doing, its throwing me this error:"An item with the same key has already been added".

Comment: If you add three images all with the same key K, then what do you want FindControl to return when you pass K to it? If any of the three images would be acceptable, then you could put an `if (!this._imageLookup.ContainsKey(uri))` before you add to the lookup.  Or, maybe you should use a different key.

Comment: This contains different name while binding the image from a same location.

Comment: My answer now uses the control's name for the key instead of the URI.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Silverlight Toolkit, then you don't need this maintain this helper method yourself, because it comes with a similar one already as an extension method.

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;

// ...

private void DoStuff()
{
    var myImage = this.MyRootLayoutPanel.GetVisualDescendants().OfType<Image>()
        .Where(img => img.Name == "MyImageName").FirstOrDefault();
}
```

**Alternatively**, I don't know your exact scenario, but if you're crafting a properly templated `Control` rather than a simple `UserControl` or `Page`, you'd just do

```
public class MyFancyControl : Control
{
    public MyFancyControl()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(MyFancyControl);
    }

    // ...

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        var myImage = this.GetTemplateChild("MyImageName") as Image;
    }
}
```